# recall ajax in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$function(){ and $window.onload()` - I'm not sure how to handle this? On the `$('#ashift').on('click',function(){` I need the ajax call to fire again? should I wrap it in a function and call the function on page load and then again in the click event, or is there a better way - I need the `clicked_shift` variable to update in the ajax call.

```
 <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var clicked_shift = "C";

  $('#ashift').on('click', function(){
    clicked_shift = "A";
  });

  $(function () {

    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'county.php',                         
      data: {action:"tt"},                                             
      dataType: 'json',                   
      success: function(data){
      alert(clicked_shift);
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (val.completed == 1) {
            color = "green";
            } else {
            color = "red";
            }
            if (val.Shift == clicked_shift){
                $('#station'+val.Station+' .snum').append("<span style='color:"+color+"'>" + val.LastName + "</span><br/>"); 
            }
        });
      } 

    }); // end ajax
}); // end of function()
  </script>
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated for an extremely long time.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: i'm stuck with ver 1.3 for now

Comment: are you saying `$(document).on( click, .ajax, function(){} );` would reload the ajax?

Comment: ok replace `.live` with `.on` : any help with original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 var clicked_shift = "C";
function ajaxCall(){ // function declaration
  console.log("clicked_shift",clicked_shift);
}

  $(function () {
    ajaxCall(); // call function ondomready
    
  $('#ashift').live('click',function(){
    clicked_shift = "A"; // change variable value
    ajaxCall(); // re-invoke the function
  });
}); // end of function()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ashift">click</div>
```

`$(function(){});` is like `$(document).ready(function(){});` a self invoked anonymous function which will be triggered when dom is fully loaded. To re-invoke a function later, you need to declare it or to assign it to a variable.`